# Computing left handed Riemann Sums in Haskell

Tags: haskell, calculus

I have created this function that is supposed to compute left handed Riemann sums but I am getting an answer of infinity every time I call the function. I am confused on why I would be returned infinity even though I am taking the sum of a finite list and multiplying it by deltaX.

```hs
theFunc :: Float -> Float  
theFunc x = 1 / x^2 

--aBound, bBound, function, numIntervals  
leftSum :: Float -> Float ->  (Float -> Float) -> Float -> Float  
leftSum a b f n =   
    let dx = (b-a) / n  
    in dx * (sum [f x | x <- [a,a+dx..b-dx]])
```

Comment: Can you show how you *call* the function? If `x` is `0`, then `theFunc 0` will be `Infinity`.

Comment: Yes I see the issue now and when I don't have zero included in my interval I am returned a finite value. I would have figured that this would just return a zero for that subinterval.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect 0. The sum isn't defined if `theFunc` isn't defined over `[a, b]`. The right answer *is* infinity, in the sense that the value grows arbitrarily large as `a` decreases towards 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will only happen when the left interval of the Reimann sum begins at 0 because of the line:

```
in dx * (sum [f x | x <- [a,a+dx..b-dx]])
```

`f x` given your `theFunc` function becomes `theFunc 0` and `1/0^2` is `infinity`

Since mathematically speaking there is an asymptote at 0, this behavior is correct.
If you instead want to pretend that a value at 0 does not contribute to the integral, then we can add a guard for zero like so:

```
theFunc :: Float -> Float
theFunc x
  | x == 0.0 = 0.0
  | otherwise = 1.0 / x^2
```

Called like:

```
leftSum 0 2 theFunc 1000
```